# Spark NLP Evaluation (com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.eval._) for Scala 2.12?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nlp, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

Spark NLP Evaluation `com.johnsnowlabs.nlp.eval._` for Scala `2.12.x` not available. With  spark version `3.x`, it's not working with libraryDependency `"com.johnsnowlabs.nlp" %% "spark-nlp-eval" % "2.2.2"` in sbt. There is no repo for Scala version `2.12.x` at
https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/johnsnowlabs/nlp/

The procedure given for Evaluating NER DL at https://github.com/JohnSnowLabs/spark-nlp/blob/master/docs/en/evaluation.md#evaluating-ner-dl is not working.

Anyone knows how to perform NER evaluation in Spark NLP using Scala ?

Comment: It seems that this package is not released for 2.12. Latest release is three years ago. Use "com.johnsnowlabs.nlp" %% "spark-nlp" % "4.2.3"

Comment: I am already using `"com.johnsnowlabs.nlp" %% "spark-nlp" % "4.2.3"`. It's not working

Comment: what is the error?